# passing properties to child task of composed-task-runner app of spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, shell, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to run composed-task-runner of spring cloud data flow, which has 2 child tasks (A and B) within it. I am passing properties to my-composed-task, which has to be passed to child tasks too, but it is not passing into the child applications.
Below are the commands which I am using:

for the creation of task in dataflow shell:

```
task create my-composed-task --definition "A && B"
```

for launching the task in dataflow shell:

```
task launch my-composed-task --arguments "--spring.cloud.task.closecontextEnabled=true --increment-instance-enabled=true --composed-task-arguments=measurementyear=2020,--logging.level.org=ERROR,--spring.datasource.url=url,--spring.datasource.username=username,--spring.datasource.password=password" --properties "deployer.composed-task-runner.local.javaOpts=-Xmx8g"
```

the properties argument **"deployer.composed-task-runner.local.javaOpts=-Xmx8g"** is not going into the child applications of  **my-composed-task**.

After launching through dataflow shell, server shows below commands for the task created:

my-composed-task

```
o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher      : Command to be executed: C:\Program Files\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\bin\java.exe -Xmx8g -jar C:\Users\shivani.chittauri\Desktop\jar\composedtaskrunner-task-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar --spring.cloud.task.closecontextEnabled=true --composed-task-arguments=measurementyear=2020,--spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8,--logging.level.org=ERROR,--spring.datasource.url=url,--spring.datasource.username=username,--spring.datasource.password=password --increment-instance-enabled=true --spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.local.accounts.default.javaOpts=-Xmx8g --spring.cloud.data.flow.platformname=default --spring.cloud.task.executionid=49 --spring.cloud.data.flow.taskappname=composed-task-runner
```

> It has javaOpts as -Xmx8g, which is correct

Task A

```
o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher      : Command to be executed: C:\Program Files\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\bin\java.exe -jar C:\Users\shivani.chittauri\Desktop\jar\A-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.datasource.username=username --spring.datasource.url=url --spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8 --logging.level.org=ERROR --spring.datasource.password=password measurementyear=2020 --spring.cloud.data.flow.platformname=default --spring.cloud.task.executionid=50
```

> It does not has javaOpts, but it should have

Task B

```
o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalTaskLauncher      : Command to be executed: C:\Program Files\jdk1.8.0_152\jre\bin\java.exe -jar C:\Users\shivani.chittauri\Desktop\jar\B-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.datasource.username=username --spring.datasource.url=url --spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8 --logging.level.org=ERROR --spring.datasource.password=password measurementyear=2020 --spring.cloud.data.flow.platformname=default --spring.cloud.task.executionid=51
```

> It does not has javaOpts, but it should have

I want javaOpts to be present in child tasks too, what could be done to resolve it???

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I actually have a similar question.. I want to mount a volume via the deployer.<app>.volume field to all child tasks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the `app` or `deployer` properties into the child tasks, then you need to reference the `app or label` name of the child task in order to qualify them for the child tasks.

For example, in your case, you need to use something like this:

```
deployer.my-composed-task.A.local.javaOpts=-Xmx8g
```

You see the name of the composed task `my-composed-task` with the name of the child task `A` in the above property reference.

For more information on this, you can check the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_passing_properties_to_the_child_tasks)