# Spring Cloud Dataflow Volume Mounts for Composed Tasks

Tags: spring, kubernetes, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

Can you mount volumes on composed tasks?

I see you can pass arguments to composed tasks as follows:

```
 --arguments "--composed-task-arguments=--app.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql:XXXXX"
```

and pass properties to the deployer to mount volumes as so:

```
 --properties "deployer.*.kubernetes.volumeMounts=[{name: 'myName', mountPath: 
'/test'}], deployer.*.kubernetes.volumes=[{name: 'myName', persistentVolumeClaim: { 
claimName: 'myName'}}]"
```

However in doing so I only see the volume mounted on the composed task runner and not child tasks spawned from it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the answer to the question: [passing properties to child task of composed-task-runner app of spring cloud dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62674066/passing-properties-to-child-task-of-composed-task-runner-app-of-spring-cloud-dat)

To be precise, you need to do something like this:

```
deployer.<name-of-your-composed-task>.<child task name/label>.kubernetes.volumeMounts=***
```

The documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_passing_properties_to_the_child_tasks) can help you understand this better as well.

Comment: So I'm looking to set the heap space -Xmx arg for child tasks of the composed task.. Am I right in understanding this should be able to be done with the following: `deployer.<app-name>.*.kubernetes.environmentVariables=JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xmx1024m` .. I only see the the message `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m` on the composed task runner with the above and not the child tasks